# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'InjectionMember[]' because it is not a delegate type. - How can use DI in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have written asp.net core application and used below code for dependency injection, which is working fine as expected.

```
services.AddScoped<IDeviceRepository<Device>>(factory =>
{
    return new DeviceRepository<Device>(
        new AzureTableSettings(
            storageAccount: Configuration.GetConnectionString("Table_StorageAccount"),
            storageKey: Configuration.GetConnectionString("Table_StorageKey"),
            tableName: Configuration.GetConnectionString("Table_TableName")));
});
```

Due to some reason I am moving back to ASP.NET MVC application, and I have to use 3rd party library for dependency injection. So I have used Unity framework.

```
container.RegisterType<IDeviceRepository<Device>>(factory =>
{
    return new DeviceRepository<Device>(
        new AzureTableSettings(
            storageAccount: Configuration.GetConnectionString("Table_StorageAccount"),
            storageKey: Configuration.GetConnectionString("Table_StorageKey"),
            tableName: Configuration.GetConnectionString("Table_TableName")));
});
```

But, I am getting error as follow

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Suppression State   Line
>   Error   CS1660  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'InjectionMember[]' because it is not a delegate type  \Presentation\Web\App_Start\UnityConfig.cs  Active  60

Here is my **DeviceRepository** Class

```
public class DeviceRepository<T>: IDeviceRepository<T>
where T : TableEntity, new()
{
    ...
}
```

My **AzureTableSettings** class

```
public class AzureTableSettings
{
    public AzureTableSettings(string storageAccount,
                                   string storageKey,
                                   string tableName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storageAccount))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("StorageAccount");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storageKey))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("StorageKey");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("TableName");

        this.StorageAccount = storageAccount;
        this.StorageKey = storageKey;
        this.TableName = tableName;
    }

    public string StorageAccount { get; }
    public string StorageKey { get; }
    public string TableName { get; }
}
```

How can use Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC application for this type of class?

**Issue Resolved and here is the Solution**

First register the type as follow

```
     container.RegisterType<IDeviceRepository<Device>>(
        new InjectionFactory(c => CreateDeviceRepository()));
```

Here is the **CreateDeviceRepository** method

```
       public static IDeviceRepository<Device> CreateDeviceRepository()
       {
             return new DeviceRepository<Device>(
                    new AzureTableSettings(
               storageAccount:Configuration.GetConnectionString("Table_StorageAccount"),
        storageKey: Configuration.GetConnectionString("Table_StorageKey"),
        tableName: Configuration.GetConnectionString("Table_TableName")));
                });
      }
```

Comment: How it's duplicate ?

Comment: It is a duplicate, because the referenced question describes exactly how to create a lambda-based registration in Unity.

Comment: Issue resolved! I would update the answer

Answer (score -1):

For my understanding, the error tells you to inherit from InjectionMember:

```
public class DeviceRepository<T>: InjectionMember, IDeviceRepository<T>
where T : TableEntity, new()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: InjectionMember is part of Unity and adding it's reference in repository make it tightly coupled. I wish to make changes only in web application, not in repositories or domain classes. I suspect it is syntax issue.

Comment: Have a look to the docs. You need to implement `InjectionMember` for `UnityContainer.RegisterType`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainer.registertype.aspx